# Playing Audio in WPF with repeat on finish

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Hi I want to create a audio player class but having some problems like when audio is finished it is not repeating. While playing audio some UI controls are not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `MediaElement` to play the audio, you can handle the `MediaEnded` event and call the `Play` method in the handler

```
Private Sub MediaElement_MediaEnded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)

    Dim m As MediaElement = CType(sender, MediaElement)
    m.Play()

End Sub
```